# Is $\langle x^2-x-1 \rangle$ a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that

> $$\langle x^2-x-1 \rangle \text{ is not a maximal ideal of } \mathbb{Z}[x].$$

**My attempt:** I am not that much familiar with field theory but i know that an ideal $I$ is maximal over a commutative ring $R$ iff $\displaystyle\frac{R}{I}$ is a field ,but here $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ is a UFD and given ideal is  irreduicble over $\mathbb{Z[x]}$ so it is prime and thus $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z[x]}}{\langle x^2-x-1 \rangle }$ is an integral domain ,but don't know about is it field or not?

Comment: Can you find a larger proper ideal, for example what do you get when quotienting by $2$ ? Otherwise what is the characteristic of $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-x-1)$ and does it contain the smallest field of that characteristic ?

Comment: Quotienting by 2 mean $\frac{\mathbb{Z[x]}}{<2>}$ which is $\mathbb{Z_{2}[x]}$

Comment: Quotienting the quotient not $\Bbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: is itl $\frac{\mathbb{Z_{2}[x]}}{<x^2-x-1>}$ ? i just guessed it .

Comment: Alternatively you could define or construct it by $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle 2,x^2-x-1 \rangle$.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z_{2}[x]}/(x^2-x-1)$ the zero ring or is it a true ring, if so what does it means about the ideal $(2,x^2-x-1)$

Comment: ok here this ideal is contained in $(2,(x^2-x-1))$ ideal so the given ideal is not maximal (as per the defination of maximal ideal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal is not maximal,  because $ (2, x^2-x-1) $ is a proper ideal properly containing it.

To see it is a proper ideal, note that there do not exist $f,g\in\Bbb Z[x]$ with $f(x)\cdot 2+g(x)\cdot(x^2-x+1)= 1$.

To see that the containment is proper note that $2\not\in(x^2-x+1)$.

Comment: what can we say about ideal $(3,x^2-x-1)$ is this ideal also contain the given ideal?

Comment: I believe it will also work,  as $(3, x^2-x+1)\ne(1)$.

Comment: That is, of course it contains the given ideal.  And it also possesses the other features necessary to show the given ideal is not maximal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks.   Foiled again.  May as well just go with $1$.